# angular timer is not working in my app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angular application angular-timer directive is not working. I have added angular-timer.js reference in my index.html.But its not working.

I tried to use timer directive like as described in the angular page http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html#/timer-with-start-time

Please suggest me where could I have gone wrong.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: can you post your code how do you load angular and angular-timer.js and make sure you initiate angular with ng-app directive in your html

Comment: I have solved the above problem by injecting  module to my app. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the above problem by injecting module to my app.

var app=   angular
    .module('app', [
      'timer'
    ]);

Thanks All